# Php not work if install from source but work with yum

Tags: php, apache, centos

I installed apache and php. but when i install php by yum apache work well. but if i install php by complied source code apache only show code .

[image: php version after install from soure]

[image: apache after php installed from source]

Comment: Did you mean when you install PHP by source code, it shows the structure of the folder instead of autoloading index.php?

Comment: @catcon yes it my problem . if i use yum every work fine.

Comment: When you click on `index.php`, will it run? If so, your PHP is fine, it's your apache's setting.

Comment: i click on index.php it only show code by text. not run

Comment: Make sure apache load php5 module, take a look at this: https://serverfault.com/questions/738441/php-not-working-with-apache-on-centos-7

Comment: when i use `yum install php` it works well . but when complied by source code it not work .. my boss said me update server php by source code dont use `yum` :( so sad

Answer (score 1):

check in `var/log/apache2/error.log` to see if you have any errors.

And also install this

```
yum install php libapache2-mod-php
yum a2enmod mpm_prefork && yum a2enmod php7.0
service apache2 restart
```

I was in the same problem in **Ubuntu** hope `yum` command will work with it